# Pillow and Python won't open large images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I work with archival images which can very in size. In the past, I processed large collection but moderately-sized image files using my Python script that used Pillow. However, I now have a large collection of 16-bit RGB TIFF files that are an average of 150 mb per file and they refuse to open with Pillow.

```
from PIL import Image
filename = "FELAA011a.tif"    # This is 144 mb tiff, with 16-bit RGB color
im = Image.open(filename)
```

I get the following error message.

```
OSError: cannot identify image file 'FELAA011a.tif'
```

It opens in Photoshop, MediaInfo shows it's a tiff. Heck, even Windows Photo Viewer has no problem.

Does pillow have an upper limit in file sizes in what it can handle?

Comment: Hello, Have you tried any other libraries for image processing like scipy.ndimage which has a function ndimage.imread? I found that this library has a lot of interesting image treatment functionality. Check out: http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/

Comment: Have you tried resizing the image in Photoshop to try and work out at what point it is able to load the image?

Comment: Photoshop has no problem with resizing the image. I haven't tried Scipy but I had the same problem when I tried it with Numpy. I'll give that a shot when I get a free moment. The only place it seems to fail is opening it with Python using Pillow and Numpy.

Comment: Nope. ndimage.imread seems to call PIL as well which then gives me the same error message. Dang... Any other ideas?

Comment: There is an [upper limit](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1475), 2 ** 28 bit, but that gives an overflow error (and will be fixed soon). Please can you post the full stack trace? Which version of Pillow are you using (`pip freeze | grep -i pillow`)? If Pillow 3.0.0 doesn't work, does Pillow 2.9.0 work (`pip install pillow==2.9.0`)?

Comment: Got the same problem with a tiff that really look common. file says "TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=15, height=1152, bps=0, compression=none, PhotometricIntepretation=RGB, width=2048", mediainfo says : Format                                   : TIFF
File size : 13.5 MiB
Image Format: Raw
Width: 2 048 pixels
Height: 1 152 pixels
Color space: RGB
Bit depth : 16 bits
Compression mode : Lossless